# Scala Set - default behavior

Tags: scala, set, scala-collections

Want to know how scala arranges the data in set.

```
scala> val imm = Set(1, 2, 3, "four")                  //immutable variable
imm  : scala.collection.immutable.Set[Any] = Set(1, 2, 3, four)

scala> var mu = Set(1, 2, 3, "four", 9)  
mu: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Any] = Set(four, 1, 9, 2, 3)

scala> mu += "five"

scala> mu.toString 
res1: String = Set(four, 1, 9, 2, 3, five)
```

Order remains as we insert in case of immutable Set but not in mutable Set.
Also no matter how many times I create a new set with var `xyz = Set(1, 2, 3, "four", 9)` the order of getting stored remains same `Set(four, 1, 9, 2, 3)`. So it's not storing in random, there is some logic behind it which I want to know. Moreover, is there any advantage of such behavior?

Comment: "it's not storing in random, there is some logic behind it" - well, did you expect there be no logic behind it? Also, computers are pretty bad at being "random". Google "hash table".

Comment: Unless you use the sorted impl (`SortedSer`), set only guarantee elements are unique,  nothing about order, which is there implementation detail. If want to know, you could look at source of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sets don't have an order. An item is in the set or it isn't. That's all you can know about a set.

If you require a certain ordering, you need to use an ordered set or possibly a sorted set.

Of course, any particular implementation of a set may or may not incidentally have an ordering which may or may not be stable across multiple calls, but that would be a purely accidental implementation detail that may change at any time, during an update of Scala or even between two calls.

Comment: To be exact, Sets do have an ordering, it merely isn't insertion ordering.

Comment: @Jorg W Mittag, I agree with your point that this behavior may change during further updates of Scala. Because, an immutable Set following the insertion order and a mutable Set not following the insertion order, makes no sense to me.